# UID of script "/var/www/html/phpinfo.php" is smaller than min_uid

Tags: permissions, php, apache2.4

My Apache works and I get the default page when I access it from a browser.
But when I created a PHP test script phpinfo.php and placed it in `/var/www/html` I get the following error occuring in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:350 : UID of script "/var/www/html/phpinfo.php" is smaller than min_uid
```

I can find nothing on the internet to resolve this!
The only suggestion that seemed relevant was to change the ownership of phpinfo.php.
The ownership of files in  `/var/www/html` are as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 26 09:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 25 20:44 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 11510 Jan 25 20:45 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    22 Jan 26 09:43 phpinfo.php
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're running suPHP judging by the error. www-data has a uid and gid of less than 500. Create a new user for that website with a uid over 500 and associated group with a gid higher than 500, and chown those files to that new user. There may be some other settings that need changing (been a little while since I've used suphp), but that's the crux of your problem - uid and gid of www-data are below 500.

Answer (score -1):

Just disable the suPHP mode in apache2,
by typing this command on terminal:

```
sudo a2dismod suphp
```

If you want to enable it again:

```
sudo a2enmod suphp
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the initial question, and it's over a year old.  If you're having an issue, please post it as a new question.  Otherwise, disabling suphp in this case, isn't an answer.